# RangeError (end): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..70: -1 flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to compress an Image using [flutter image compress package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_compress)

```
Future<File> testCompressAndGetFile(File file) async {

  final lastIndex = file.absolute.path.lastIndexOf(new RegExp(r'.jp')); //this returns -1

    final splitted = file.absolute.path.substring(0, (lastIndex)); // I always get the error from here

    String oP = "${splitted}_ql${file.absolute.path.substring(lastIndex)}";

    final result = await FlutterImageCompress.compressAndGetFile(
      file.absolute.path,
      oP,
      quality: 95,
    );

    return result;
}
```

when i print the **lastIndex**, i get `-1` which is not in the range of 0-70.
and because of this **splitted** throws the error

```
RangeError (end): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..70: -1
```

Please how do i fix this error

Comment: The problem is mostly like in your file combined with the regex. What is a file and its path that you are trying to compress using this function?

Answer (score 1):

The `-1` value of `lastIndex` from [`lastIndexOf`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-core/String/lastIndexOf.html) indicates that the pattern was not found. So `.jp` is in fact not in your input. You should either guard and return early or throw your on exception if this is a valid use case.

For what it's worth, a `String` implements `Pattern` so there is no need to instantiate a `RegExp` for this pattern. This would work just fine. `.lastIndexOf('.jp')`.

Comment: ok will try it. thanks